# React Jodit Editor loses focus on onchange method and useMemo doesn't work well

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jodit

I am creating a component where I have a form with some inputs and a text editor, which in this case is Jodit.

The problem is that when there are changes in the content of the Jodit editor, I need to get the new value in HTML, and I think this is only possible with the onChange method, and the onChange method has a problem: when it is called the editor loses focus.

I tried to solve this problem, and I found some ways that worked using useMemo, but there was another problem: if I used useMemo directly on the return of my React component, the inputs couldn't change their value, no matter how much I typed it was still in the original value of my state. The other way was to add the editor config inside the useMemo, which somehow worked, but when typing the cursor returns to the beginning of the text out of nowhere.

Here is my component:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import JoditEditor from 'jodit-react'
import { useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { Button, FloatingLabel, Form } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import PageTitle from '../../../../template/admin/page_title/PageTitle'

function ArticleEdite() {
    const editor = useRef(null)
    const params = useParams()
    const [article, setArticle] = useState({
        id: '',
        name: '',
        description: '',
        imageUrl: '',
        content: '',
        categoryId: '',
    })

    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([])
    const [method, setMethod] = useState('post')

    useEffect(() => {
        const { id } = params

        if (id === 'new') {
            setMethod('post')
        } else {
            setMethod('put')
            loadArticle()
        }

        loadCategories()
    }, [params])

    const updateArticle = ({ type, object, field, value }) => {
        if (type === 'object' && object) {
            setArticle((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, ...object }))
        } else if (type === 'field' && field) {
            setArticle((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [field]: value }))
        }
        console.log(article)
    }

    const loadArticle = () => {
        // load article
    }

    const loadCategories = () => {
        // load categories
    }

    const save = () => {
        // save
    }

    const config = useMemo(
        () => ({
            zIndex: 0,
            readonly: false,
            activeButtonsInReadOnly: ['source', 'fullsize', 'print', 'about'],
            toolbarButtonSize: 'middle',
            theme: 'default',
            enableDragAndDropFileToEditor: true,
            saveModeInCookie: false,
            spellcheck: true,
            editorCssClass: false,
            triggerChangeEvent: true,
            height: 450,
            direction: 'ltr',
            language: 'pt_BR',
            debugLanguage: false,
            i18n: 'en',
            tabIndex: -1,
            toolbar: true,
            enter: 'P',
            useSplitMode: false,
            colorPickerDefaultTab: 'background',
            imageDefaultWidth: 100,
            removeButtons: ['about', 'print', 'file'],
            disablePlugins: ['paste', 'stat'],
            events: {},
            textIcons: false,
            uploader: {
                insertImageAsBase64URI: true,
            },
            placeholder: '',
            showXPathInStatusbar: false,
        }),
        []
    )

    return (
        <div className='article-edite'>
            <ToastContainer />
            <PageTitle
                icon='file'
                title='Edite sua postagem'
                subtitle='Edite sua postagem com criatividade e veracidade'
            />
            <Form>
                <Form.Label htmlFor='article-name'>Nome:</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                    id='article-name'
                    placeholder='Informe o nome do artigo...'
                    onChange={(event) =>
                        updateArticle({
                            type: 'field',
                            field: 'name',
                            value: event.target.value,
                        })
                    }
                    value={article.name}
                    className='mb-3'
                />
                <Form.Label htmlFor='article-description'>
                    Descrição:
                </Form.Label>
                <FloatingLabel
                    controlId='article-description'
                    label='Informe a descrição do artigo...'
                >
                    <Form.Control
                        as='textarea'
                        placeholder='Informe a descrição do artigo...'
                        style={{ height: '100px' }}
                        value={article.description}
                        onChange={(event) =>
                            updateArticle({
                                type: 'field',
                                field: 'description',
                                value: event.target.value,
                            })
                        }
                        maxLength={1000}
                    />
                </FloatingLabel>
                <p
                    className='text-secondary text-end mb-3'
                    style={{ fontSize: '0.6rem' }}
                >
                    Máximo de 1000 caracteres
                </p>
                <Form.Label htmlFor='article-image'>Imagem:</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                    id='article-image'
                    placeholder='Informe a url da imagem de capa do artigo...'
                    value={article.imageUrl}
                    onChange={(event) =>
                        updateArticle({
                            type: 'field',
                            field: 'imageUrl',
                            value: event.target.value,
                        })
                    }
                    className='mb-3'
                />
                <Form.Label htmlFor='article-content'>Conteúdo:</Form.Label>
                <JoditEditor
                    id='article-content'
                    ref={editor}
                    value={article.content}
                    config={config}
                    tabIndex={1}
                    onChange={(newContent) =>
                        updateArticle({
                            type: 'field',
                            field: 'content',
                            value: newContent,
                        })
                    }
                />
                <Form.Label
                    htmlFor='article-category'
                    className='mt-3'
                >
                    Categoria:
                </Form.Label>
                <Form.Select
                    id='article-category'
                    aria-label='Selecione uma categoria'
                    value={article.categoryId}
                    onSelect={(event) =>
                        updateArticle({
                            type: 'field',
                            field: 'categoryId',
                            value: event.target.value,
                        })
                    }
                >
                    {categories.map((category) => (
                        <option
                            key={category.value}
                            value={category.value}
                        >
                            {category.text}
                        </option>
                    ))}
                </Form.Select>
                <Button
                    variant='primary'
                    onClick={save}
                    style={{ height: '55px', width: '55px' }}
                    className='rounded-circle position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 m-5'
                >
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fas', 'save']} />
                </Button>
            </Form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ArticleEdite
```

Answer (score 1):

Use onBlur instead! Had same issue..

Answer (score 0):

remove onChange of JoditEditor. You use "editor.value" to get data from JoditEditor. When submit button save call "editor.value" to setArticle.content